# Autocomplete UI + json, забрать в переменные

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, jquery-ui

Есть такой обработчик search.php:

```
function getDbConnection() {
  $db = new PDO(DB_DRIVER . ":dbname=" . DB_DATABASE . ";host=" . DB_SERVER . ";charset=utf8", DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
  return $db;
}

function serachForKeyword($keyword) {

  $results = array();

    $db = getDbConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT s.name1 value, i.name icon FROM prefix_shop s JOIN prefix_images i ON s.id = i.element_id WHERE i.module_name = 'shop' and s.trash = '0' and s.name1 LIKE '%{$keyword}%' GROUP BY s.name1");
    $isQueryOk = $stmt->execute();
    if ($isQueryOk) {
       while (($row = $stmt->fetch() ) )
         {
          $results[] = array(
           'icon' => $row['icon'],
           'value' => $row['value']
          );
          }
    } else {
        trigger_error('Error executing statement.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
     $db = null; 

    return $results;
}



if (!isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
    die("die");
}

 $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
 $data = serachForKeyword($keyword);
 echo json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_APOS);
```

На выходе по запросу: `?keyword=gopro` получаю примерно такие данные:

```
   [
      {
        "icon": "6415_gopro-hero4-black-edition-adventure.jpg",
        "value": "GoPro Hero4 Black Edition Adventure"
      },
      {
        "icon": "6416_gopro-hero4-silver-edition-adventure.jpg",
        "value": "GoPro Hero4 Silver Edition Adventure"
      },
      {
        "icon": "8388_gopro-avtomobilnoe-zaryadnoe-.png",
        "value": "GoPro \u0410\u0432\u0442\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0431\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0437\u0430\u0440\u044f\u0434\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0443\u0441\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e Auto Charger"
      },
      {
        "icon": "415_bokovoe-kreplenie-gopro-side-mount.jpg",
        "value": "GoPro \u0411\u043e\u043a\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0435 \u041a\u0440\u0435\u043f\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 Side Mount"
      },
      {
        "icon": "435_gopro-bolty-alyuminievye-sinie.jpg",
        "value": "GoPro \u0411\u043e\u043b\u0442\u044b \u0430\u043b\u044e\u043c\u0438\u043d\u0438\u0435\u0432\u044b\u0435 \u0441\u0438\u043d\u0438\u0435 UNLIM UN-HR51"
      }
    ]
```

И сам вопрос:

```
$('#input-id').autocomplete({
       url:'search.php',
       data:'keyword='+keyword,
       success: "как сюда засунуть полученные данные в виде: <ul><img src="http://site.com/img/ + data.icon +">+ data.value +</ul>" что бы каждую найденную пару результатов выводил с новой строки"
});
```

**UPDATE**

Ладно уже хотя бы не в `autocomplete`, а хотя бы просто на `javascript`'е дайте:
пример того как взять каждую пару `icon` и `value`, и их занести в одну переменную.

**UPDATE2**

При таком коде:

```
$.ajax({
                        url:'auto-complete.php',
                        data:'keyword='+keyword,

                        success: function(d) {
                        console.log(d);
                        }
```

Вот такой результат:
[image: результат1]

При таком коде:

```
            $.ajax({
                url:'auto-complete.php',
                data:'keyword='+keyword,
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(d) {
                console.log(d);
                }
```

Результат такой:

[image: результат2]

но с `d.data` не в одном не в другом случаи не чего не выводит, пишет: `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил задачу так:

```
$.ajax({
            url:'auto-complete.php',
            data:'keyword='+keyword,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(d){
            $.each(d, function(i, val) {
            console.log(val.icon + val.value);
            console.log(i);
            })
            }
```

и сапаибо *Andrew Godin*

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой код выведет данные в консоль:

```
$('#input-id').autocomplete({
    url:'search.php',
    data:'keyword='+keyword,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui.item.value + " --- " + ui.item.icon);
    }
});
```

В консоли Вы увидите свои данные. Чтобы разместить данные где-то на странице, нужно подготовить какой-то контейнер для из получения, и воспользоваться методом .html() из библиотеки jquery.

Comment: да я найду куда вывести результат, дайте мне пример того как взять каждую пару `icon` и `value`, и их занести в одну переменную

Comment: '<img src="site.com/img/' + d.data.icon +'">'+ d.data.value

Comment: обновил вопрос по вашему комментарию

Comment: Вообще откуда Вы взяли icon? Вроде бы у автокомплита всегда было id, title, value.

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел доку по автокомплиту. Нет там никакого success. Сейчас поправлю свой ответ.

Comment: мой вариант уже отвязан от автокоплита и есть просто запрос `$.Ajax`, `icon` и `value` получаю `sql` запросом: `"SELECT s.name1 value, i.name icon FROM prefix_shop s JOIN prefix_images i ON s.id = i.element_id WHERE i.module_name = 'shop' and s.trash = '0' and s.name1 LIKE '%{$keyword}%' GROUP BY s.name1"` потом заношу сюда:       `while (($row = $stmt->fetch() ) )
         {
          $results[] = array(
           'icon' => $row['icon'],
           'value' => $row['value']
          );`

Comment: Значит Вы не правильно ставите вопрос. Переформулируйте его, а этот удалите.